# Странности с созданием и использованием custom view во ViewHolder

Tags: android, customview, viewholder

У меня есть recyclerview c адаптером `ChartAdapter`, и в layout-e первого ViewHolder-а (`ProgressViewHolder`) создаётся custom view (`MyChart`):

```
 <com.android.MyChart
      android:id="@+id/chart"
      ... />
```

данные которого наполняются через метод этого ViewHolder-а:

```
class ProgressViewHolder(
    val binding: ItemProgressBinding
) : BaseAdapter.BaseViewHolder<BaseEntry>(binding) {

    override fun bind(item: BaseJourneyEntry, handler: Any?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "ProgressViewHolder, bind, $this")
        super.bind(item, handler)
        populateDataAfterLayoutReady(progressModel = item as ChartEntry)
    }

    private fun populateDataAfterLayoutReady(
        progressModel: chartEntry
    ) {
        binding.root.doOnLayout { populateData(progressModel) }
    }

    private fun populateData(сhartEntry: ChartEntry) {
        binding.chart.populateData(
            ChartData(
                values = getChartValues(сhartEntry)
            )
    )
}
```

A само это custom view (`MyChart`) выглядит следующим образом:

```
class MyChart @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private val adapterItems = mutableListOf<ChartColumnData>()

    init {
        Log.d(TAG, "init, adapterItems.count = ${adapterItems.size}, $this")
        ...
    }

    override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow()
        Log.d(TAG, "onAttachedToWindow, adapterItems.count = ${adapterItems.size}, $this")
    }


    fun populateData(data: ChartData) {
        Log.d(TAG, "populateData, adapterItems.count = ${adapterItems.size}")
        Log.d(TAG, "populateData, data.values.size = ${data.values.size}")

        if (adapterItems.isEmpty()) {
            val items = data.values
            adapterItems.addAll(items)
            Log.d(TAG, "populateData 2, adapterItems.count = ${adapterItems.size}")
        }
    }
}
```

После запуска приложения я вижу в логах следующее:

```
init, adapterItems.count = 0, com.android.MyChart{8e165bf V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0b00f3 app:id/chart}
rogressViewHolder, bind, ProgressViewHolder{7a05e16 position=0 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 no parent}
onAttachedToWindow, adapterItems.count = 0, com.android.MyChart{8e165bf V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0b00f3 app:id/chart}
populateData, adapterItems.count = 0
populateData, data.values.size = 15
populateData 2, adapterItems.count = 15
```

И в какой-то момент я из этого custom view (`MyChart`) (через listener) вызываю метод (`onEndReached`), который обновляет (добавляет) данные для наполнения этого custom view, и вызываю метод `chartAdapter?.notifyItemChanged(0)`. Данные в этом custom view (`MyChart`) обновляются и я при этом вижу в логах следующее:

```
onEndReached, adapterItems.count = 15
init, adapterItems.count = 0, com.android.MyChart{c0f2b1c V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0b00f3 app:id/chart}
ProgressViewHolder, bind, ProgressViewHolder{581934c position=0 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 no parent}
onAttachedToWindow, adapterItems.count = 0, com.android.MyChart{c0f2b1c V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0b00f3 app:id/chart}
populateData, adapterItems.count = 0
populateData, data.values.size = 28
populateData 2, adapterItems.count = 28
```

и если я снова вызываю этот метод `onEndReached` (который через listener обновляет (добавляет) данные для наполнения custom view) и вызываю метод `chartAdapter?.notifyItemChanged(0)`, в логах видно следующее:

```
onEndReached, adapterItems.count = 28
ProgressViewHolder, bind, ProgressViewHolder{7a05e16 position=0 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 no parent}
onAttachedToWindow, adapterItems.count = 15, com.android.MyChart{8e165bf V.E...... .......D 0,194-936,717 #7f0b00f3 app:id/chart}
populateData, adapterItems.count = 15
populateData, data.values.size = 41
```

То, что я вижу в логах, вызывает у меня вопрос:
каким образом получается так, что сначала создаются и используются экземпляры `ProgressViewHolder{7a05e16` и `MyChart{8e165bf`, а после первого вызова `notifyItemChanged` создаются другие экземпляры этих классов - `ProgressViewHolder{581934c` и `MyChart{c0f2b1c` (и у `MyChart` вызывается `init`), а после второго вызова `notifyItemChanged` - снова используется первые экземпляры: `ProgressViewHolder{7a05e16` и `MyChart{8e165bf` (и метод `init` у `MyChart` уже не вызывается)?